# Como actualizo el valor almacenado de un objeto con localStorage, sin tener que recargar la pagina

Tags: html5, local-storage, javascript-objeto

EL nombre de la mascota ingresado lo estoy almacenando con LocalStorage y si quiero elegir otro nombre debo actualizar la pagina e ingresar el nuevo nombre, quisiera que el nombre ingresado pueda ser reemplazado con un nuevo nombre, tan solo con darle click al boton "Guardar nombre" y no tener que darle a "recargar página"

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>My pet</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="form">
        <form  action="" >
            <p> <label for="petName">¿Cómo se va a llamar tu mascota? </label> </p> 
            <input type="text" id="petName" placeholder="ejem: sr tocino"> 
            <button type="button" id="boton_guardar_pet_name" onclick="saveName()">Guardar Nombre</button>
        </form>

    </div>
    
    <div id="petImg">Aqui va la imagen de la mascota</div>
    <script>
        //------------------funciones
        let petName = document.getElementById('petName').value;
        
        
        function saveName (){
            if(petName === ""){
                    document.getElementById('petName').focus();
            }else{
                
                 localStorage.setItem('objeto', JSON.stringify(pet))
            }
        }   
        

        //----------------objetos
        let pet = {
            nombre: petName,
            salud: 100,
            hambre: 0,
            popo: 0
        }

        console.log(pet)



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: OBJETO es la clave con la cual estoy guardando el obejto "pet" en el cual se almacena el nombre]

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas el código en vez de una foto del mismo si no quieres que tu pregunta reciba votos negativos y/o sea cerrada. Puedes leer esto para informarte: [Cómo preguntar en SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: una pregunta ese es tu codigo o lo copiaste de otro lugar para usarlo de ejemplo??

Comment: Francisco Nuñez, escribi el codigo yo mismo, apenas voy iniciando si ves algun error es por eso :c

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el orden en que haces las cosas en tu script, prueba a cambiarlo por este:

```
    <script>
        //------------------funciones
        function saveName (){
            /*Cogemos el valor de petName dentro de la función. 
              Esto asegura que siempre esté actualizado, 
              ya que si lo coges al iniciar la página nada más, todavía está en blanco!*/
            let petName = document.getElementById('petName').value;
            if(petName === ""){
                    document.getElementById('petName').focus();
            }else{
                //Antes de guardar el objeto pet, cambia el nombre por petName!
                pet.nombre = petName;
                 localStorage.setItem('objeto', JSON.stringify(pet))
            }
        }   
        
        //----------------objetos
        let pet = {
            nombre: petName,
            salud: 100,
            hambre: 0,
            popo: 0
        }
        console.log(pet)
    </script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ahorita mismo ire a probar.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigooo, si funcionó. :DDD